# JavaScript How to separate elements of array on diferents arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to separate elements of array each 3 positions, like this example:

```
[1, 'a', 'hellow', 2, 'b', 'world'...]
```

On:

```
[
 [1, 'a', 'hellow'], 
 [2, 'b', 'world'],
 ...
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a straightforward implementation, you could construct the array by collecting the number of desired elements into sub arrays, then adding them to the final result, like so:

```
function separate(array) {
    let result = [];

    let collected = [];
    array.forEach(item => {
        collected.push(item);
        if (collected.length === 3) {
            result.push(collected);
            collected = [];
        }
    });

    // If there are leftover elements due to the size of the array
    // not being a multiple of 3, just add them to the end.
    if (collected.length > 0) {
        result.push(collected);
    }

    return result;
}
```